# What is the purpose of ".skrold" files in my source directories?

Tags: c#, version-control, ide

I am working on a xamarin project. Whose repository is in the TFS. Recently I noticed that all the cs and xaml files have a skrold file. I checked the content of the skrold files.
They seem to be almost same other than using statements.

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
using Camera.ViewModels;
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;
```

MainPage.xaml.cs.skrold

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using XamarinPicturePicker.UI.Models;
using XamarinPicturePicker.UI.ViewModels;
using XamarinPicturePicker.UI.Views;
```

Here is an screenshot:

[image]

I searched the internet but I could not find anything about skrold files or when it is created.

Comment: Must be some application you are using that is adding these. VS does not create these normally.

Comment: Like previous commentor said, this has nothing to do with either VS or Xamarin. (I've edited title and tags correspondingly.) I don't know what "Whose repository is in the TFS" means, but those files likely keep track of some information related to the corresponding file. Are those files smaller than the corresponding file? Then perhaps a checksum related to upload/download to repository (or other network location).

Comment: Only reference I find online to `skrold`: https://github.com/iana-org/dnssec-keytools/blob/master/ksrsigner/ksrsigner.c

Comment: Are the  ".skrold" files still here if you create a new xamarin project?

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve
TFS = Microsoft Team foundation server. I decided to delete the files and run the project. The project seemed to run fine. So, I can not tell you now if those files are smaller.

Comment: @Liyun Zhang - MSFT
 I tried creating a new project. The new project does not have any skrold files.